# Extend java class in clojure: how to override only one of two similar methods?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have the following java class.

```
public class Toto {
    public void aMethod(A a) {
        System.out.println("A " + a);   
    }

    public void aMethod(B b) {
        System.out.println("B " + b);
    }
}
```

I want to override aMethod(A a) but not aMethod(B b). The only way I could do that was:

```
(ns titi
    (:gen-class :extends Toto
     :exposes-method {aMethod parentMethod}))

(defn- -aMethod [this x]
    (if (= (type x) A)
        (println "ok do something here")
        (.parentMethod this x)))
```

Is there a better way to do this? (I mean without checking type of x myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://dishevelled.net/Tricky-uses-of-Clojure-gen-class-and-AOT-compilation.html, with `:gen-class` it is possible to override by signature but I couldn't find documentation on that, so I guess it can be considered "internals" and it may break in the future.

Anyway, supposing you have your `Toto` class in package `jpkg` together with two empty classes `A` and `B`, this works for me:

```lisp
(ns Titi
(:import [jpkg A])
    (:gen-class :extends jpkg.Toto
                :exposes-method [aMethod]))

(defn- -aMethod-A [this x]
    (println "clj a"))
```

As the following `main` namespace:

```lisp
(ns main
    (:import [jpkg A B]))

(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(defn -main []
    (. (new Titi) aMethod (new A))
    (. (new Titi) aMethod (new B)))
```

prints:

```lisp
clj a
B jpkg.B@6631f5ca
```

instead of:

```lisp
clj a
clj a
```

Type hints instead seem not to help here.